# Лицензия на БД для коммерческого приложения

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, лицензирование

Добрый день! Возникла необходимость написать ПО (с++/с#) с использованием БД. ПО коммерческое. Выбор БД пал на SQLite. Возник вопрос, каковы условия использования SQLite  коммерческой организацией для разработки своего ПО?

Comment: какой смысл вы вкладываете в слово "продуктивны"? :)

Comment: Быстрые, необходимо записывать порядка 1000 строк в секунду.

Comment: Еще такой момент не понятен, по SQLite, на официальном сайте висит информация, что "все free, можете использовать не беспокойтесь", но есть отдельная "гарантия права собственности", которая стоит 6000 usd. Будучи коммерческой организацией, какие риски существуют при использовании в своем ПО SQLite без данного "гарантийного права собственности" за 6000 usd?

Comment: где такая страница у sqlite с 6k$?  я что-то не нашел. использовать его вы можете свободно, главное копирайты не тереть)

Comment: "продуктивны" слишком растянутое понятие. смотря как БД используются. например на простых запросах MySQL может быть гораздо быстрее других БД, но если запросы более серьезные, то она может отставать и в ней например нет нормальной поддержки рекурсивных запросов (если они вдруг нужны вашим данным). Так что БД надо выбирать уже достаточно подробно представляя что на ней предполагается делать, какова структура данных. в каждой БД есть свои фичи, которые могут быть очень полезны в каких то конкретных случаях

Comment: @tcpack4 https://www.hwaci.com/cgi-bin/license-step1? 
Ответ представителя их компании такой "The warranty of title is a legal document asserting that SQLite is 100% written from scratch, that it does not use any IP from third parties, and that the authors of SQLite have placed the whole thing into the public domain.  (Note that all of the contributors to SQLite live in jurisdictions where it is legal for authors to dedicate their work into the public domain.)  The warranty of title is legal certification of the public-domain status of SQLite.
A warranty of title is $6000.00 USD.
"

Comment: @Mike запросы будут самые простые, записать строку, прочитать строку, строк будет много..

Comment: Вроде бы, данная "гарантия права собственности" говорит больше не о праве владения лично вами данной БД, а о вообще ее чистоте, это в каком то роде больше похоже на сертификат насколько я понимаю, вот этот вопрос хотелось бы уточнить.. То есть, исключить в будущем возможность со стороны этой же компании предъявить претензии по использованию их БД в своем проекте. Исключить можно когда на руках есть документ подтверждающий официально право использования. А помимо данного документа за 6000 долларов, там в принципе ничего нет.

Comment: @engineer_7 нет, sqlite под "общественным достоянием", т.е его свободно можно использовать, модифицировать и т.д, лишь бы сохранить авторство. По данной ссылке проясняется для чего необходимы 6к. Если тебе нужно документально подтвердить, к примеру при переиспользовании sqlite сорс кода, что он изначально написан с нуля и ни строчки чужого (юридически авторского) кода не использует. И только для тех стран, где не закреплено юр понятие "общественное достояние". Т.е они за деньги предоставляют такой документ.

Comment: @tcpack4 Понял Вас, это я и хотел уточнить, спасибо! Тогда остановлюсь на SQLite. По отзывам похоже, что он действительно lite, не требует установки, что хорошо, да и прост в использовании.  То что нужно.

Comment: @tcpack4 оформите ваш комментарий в виде ответа, просто хороший ответ утонет в каментах...

Comment: @Barmaley без проблем)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQLite имеет открытый код и распространяется под Public domain (Общественное достояние),
т.е для него лицензия не нужна. 
(при этом право на авторство сохраняется)

> For a one-time fee of US $6000.00 we will add your company name and contact information to a copy of the sample license agreement

касается только тех стран, в которых "Общественное достояние" не закреплено в законодательстве
либо пользователю нужно получить юр. документ, подтвержающий, что код SQLite не имеет проблем с авторским правом и компания-пользователь легально его использует.